# Count number of binary intersections (AND) for each element with other elements of array

Tags: arrays, combinatorics, bitwise-and

While solving another complicated problem, I've got this one: I have array of longs, for example, in a binary representation it would look like:

```
   0000100 
   0000100 
   0000101 
   0000001 
   0001100 
   0001101
```

for each of these longs, i have to calculate number of another longs, with whom it intersects:

```
   0000100 -> 4
   0000100 -> 4
   0000101 -> 5
   0000001 -> 2
   0001100 -> 4
   0001101 -> 5
```

Simple brute-force solution obviously requires N^2 operations and becomes unacceptably slow for me at N=20K-100K. The best stuff which I've invented, (which I believe is still suboptimal) is the following: calculate array of indexes of longs, containing certain bit for each bit:

```
  bit0: [2 3 5]
  bit1: []
  bit2: [0 1 2 4 5]
  bit3: [4 5]
```

Then I create temporary array of the same length as input array and then for each bit I can perform its own (hopefully smaller) n^2 loop. Temporary array is used to hold masks which allow to avoid double increment in the target array (which we are searching for). For me zeroes dominate ones, so usually these small n^2 are still better then grand N^2.

Also I tried sorting these longs and then building binary tree with numbers of nonzero bits attached at each level of depth. It works, but performance gain is small, because the tree itself becomes quite huge at 64bits.

One more thing, what I was doing, was sorting rows and columns of this, lets say matrix, it gave some perf. benefits to some of my approaches, but it was insignificant.

The task looks so graceful, yet I was not able to google something even close to it. How can solve this efficiently?

Comment: Would collapsing duplicate values help?

Comment: 1) in my case I don't have dup values 2) such collapsing will change target array 3) but this is productive way of thinking indeed IMO.

Comment: Sort by number of bits set and build a tree/graph rooted at zero with new connections added to leaf level nodes. Increment adjacency count for all higher level nodes?

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Unfortunately at 64bit tree gets huge, so summing over the tree happens to be slower then iteration with AND over 20K longs...